# Random TypeError: Failed to Fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm creating a web application which takes in user input and queries a flask application using a fetch request. Sometimes, this runs correctly but it randomly returns the following error message. Can you please help me fix this error?

This is an image to the error log [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih9l0.png)

[This is an image of the chrome network tab error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56UGO.png)

Here is my code:

```
async loginClick() {
        // exists represents whether or not the username was found in the Mongo database
        let exists = await this.state.IS.checkExists(this.state.username);
        alert('this compiles as expected');
        console.log(exists);
        if (exists === false) {
            alert("Username not found!");
            return;
        }

 /*** Returns True if user exists in database else false ***/
    async checkExists(user) {
        let data = {
            'u_n': 'user',
            'f_n': 'first',
            'pass': 'pass',
        };

        let bool = false;
        await Promise.resolve(
            fetch(this.config.VERIFY_URL,
                {
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                })).then(response =>
                        response.json()).then(json_msg => {
                        bool = json_msg.exists;
                        console.log(bool);
                        alert(bool);
                        return bool;
                }).catch(error => console.error(error));
        return bool;
    }
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the chrome inspector and see the error message given by the request?

Comment: I added an image of the network tab to the question!